# How to calculate a proportion in R

Tags: r, proportions

I have this reproducible DataFrame:

```
 structure(list(age = c(62.84998, 60.33899, 52.74698, 42.38498, 
 79.88495, 93.01599, 62.37097, 86.83899, 85.65594, 42.25897), 
     death = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), sex = c("male", 
     "female", "female", "female", "female", "male", "male", "male", 
     "male", "female"), hospdead = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
     0), slos = c(5, 4, 17, 3, 16, 4, 9, 7, 12, 8), d.time = c(2029, 
     4, 47, 133, 2029, 4, 659, 142, 63, 370), dzgroup = c("Lung Cancer", 
     "Cirrhosis", "Cirrhosis", "Lung Cancer", "ARF/MOSF w/Sepsis", 
     "Coma", "CHF", "CHF", "Lung Cancer", "Colon Cancer"), dzclass = c("Cancer", 
     "COPD/CHF/Cirrhosis", "COPD/CHF/Cirrhosis", "Cancer", "ARF/MOSF", 
     "Coma", "COPD/CHF/Cirrhosis", "COPD/CHF/Cirrhosis", "Cancer", 
     "Cancer"), num.co = c(0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 0), edu = c(11, 
     12, 12, 11, NA, 14, 14, NA, 12, 11), income = c("$11-$25k", 
     "$11-$25k", "under $11k", "under $11k", NA, NA, "$25-$50k", 
     NA, NA, "$25-$50k"), scoma = c(0, 44, 0, 0, 26, 55, 0, 26, 
     26, 0), charges = c(9715, 34496, 41094, 3075, 50127, 6884, 
     30460, 30460, NA, 9914), totcst = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
     NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
     NA_real_), totmcst = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
     NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
     ), avtisst = c(7, 29, 13, 7, 18.666656, 5, 8, 6.5, 8.5, 8
     ), race = c("other", "white", "white", "white", "white", 
     "white", "white", "white", "black", "hispanic"), sps = c(33.8984375, 
     52.6953125, 20.5, 20.0976562, 23.5, 19.3984375, 17.296875, 
     21.5976562, 15.8984375, 2.2998047), aps = c(20, 74, 45, 19, 
     30, 27, 46, 53, 17, 9), surv2m = c(0.262939453, 0.0009999275, 
     0.790893555, 0.698974609, 0.634887695, 0.284973145, 0.892944336, 
     0.670898438, 0.570922852, 0.952880859), surv6m = c(0.0369949341, 
     0, 0.664916992, 0.411987305, 0.532958984, 0.214996338, 0.820922852, 
     0.498962402, 0.24899292, 0.887939453), hday = c(1, 3, 4, 
     1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), diabetes = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
     0, 0), dementia = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), ca = c("metastatic", 
     "no", "no", "metastatic", "no", "no", "no", "no", "metastatic", 
     "metastatic"), prg2m = c(0.5, 0, 0.75, 0.899999619, 0.899999619, 
     0, NA, 0.799999714, 0.049999982, NA), prg6m = c(0.25, 0, 
     0.5, 0.5, 0.8999996, 0, 0.6999998, 0.3999999, 0.0001249999, 
     NA), dnr = c("no dnr", NA, "no dnr", "no dnr", "no dnr", 
     "no dnr", "no dnr", "no dnr", "dnr after sadm", "no dnr"), 
     dnrday = c(5, NA, 17, 3, 16, 4, 9, 7, 2, 8), meanbp = c(97, 
     43, 70, 75, 59, 110, 78, 72, 97, 84), wblc = c(6, 17.0976562, 
     8.5, 9.09960938, 13.5, 10.3984375, 11.6992188, 13.5996094, 
     9.69921875, 11.2988281), hrt = c(69, 112, 88, 88, 112, 101, 
     120, 100, 56, 94), resp = c(22, 34, 28, 32, 20, 44, 28, 26, 
     20, 20), temp = c(36, 34.59375, 37.39844, 35, 37.89844, 38.39844, 
     37.39844, 37.59375, 36.59375, 38.19531), pafi = c(388, 98, 
     231.65625, NA, 173.3125, 266.625, 309.5, 404.75, 357.125, 
     NA), alb = c(1.7998047, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4.7998047, NA, 
     NA, 4.6992188), bili = c(0.19998169, NA, 2.19970703, NA, 
     NA, NA, 0.39996338, NA, 0.39996338, 0.19998169), crea = c(1.19995117, 
     5.5, 2, 0.79992676, 0.79992676, 0.69995117, 1.59985352, 2, 
     1, 0.79992676), sod = c(141, 132, 134, 139, 143, 140, 132, 
     139, 143, 139), ph = c(7.459961, 7.25, 7.459961, NA, 7.509766, 
     7.65918, 7.479492, 7.509766, 7.449219, NA), glucose = c(NA_real_, 
     NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
     NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), bun = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
     NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
     NA_real_, NA_real_), urine = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
     NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
     NA_real_), adlp = c(7, NA, 1, 0, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, 0), adls = c(7, 
     1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 7, NA), sfdm2 = c(NA, "<2 mo. follow-up", 
     "<2 mo. follow-up", "no(M2 and SIP pres)", "no(M2 and SIP pres)", 
     "<2 mo. follow-up", "no(M2 and SIP pres)", NA, NA, NA), adlsc = c(7, 
     1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 7, 0.4947999)), row.names = c(NA, 10L
 ), class = "data.frame")
```

I am needing to calculate the proportion of patients who died in the hospital in patients with an active DNR order on day 3 and in patients without an active DNR order on day 3. To group which patients had an active DNR on day 3 and which did not, I used the subset function below:

```
SB_xlsx1 = SB_xlsx[!is.na(SB_xlsx$dnrday), ]
YesDNR = subset(SB_xlsx1, dnrday <= 3)
NoDNR = subset(SB_xlsx1, dnrday > 3)
```

However, I don't know how to calculate the proportion of patients that died in the hospital for those with a DNR and without a DNR. The 'hospdead' variable has all 0s and 1s, where 0 = not dead and 1 = dead. However, I don't know how to get the proportion that died for having a DNR at day 3 and did not have a DNR at day 3. What code could I use for my desired result. SB_xlsx also just represents my DataFrame name.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** I apologize; I misread your post when providing my original answer. I've revised it below.

You referred to the `hospdeath` variable, but in the toy data set it has just one nonzero entry, so I'm using the `death` variable instead to demonstrate the principle.

First, a`base` R approach:

```
mean(SB_xlsx1[SB_xlsx1$death == 1, ]$dnrday <= 3)
mean(SB_xlsx1[SB_xlsx1$death == 1, ]$dnrday > 3)
```

The idea is to restrict to the subset of rows for which a death occurred, then perform a logical check to see which entries have `dnrday` greater than 3.

Note that if you have `NA` entries in `death`, you'll want to remove them first as you did with those in `dnrday`.

---

For a `dplyr` approach:

```
library(dplyr)
SB_xlsx1 %>%
  filter(death == 1) %>%
  summarize(mean(dnrday <= 3), mean(dnrday > 3))
```

or, for a slightly nicer-looking table,

```
SB_xlsx1 %>%
  filter(death == 1) %>%
  group_by(dnrday <= 3) %>%
  summarize(prop = n() / nrow(.))
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `tapply` to group deaths by the condition `dnrday <= 3`, i.e. with an active DNR on day 3 and calculate the `mean`.

```
(res <- proportions(xtabs(death ~ dnrday <= 3, SB_xlsx)))
# dnrday <= 3
#     FALSE      TRUE 
# 0.7142857 0.2857143
```

where

```
sum(res)
# [1] 1
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would I do this for having a DNR at day and not having a DNR at day 3? I guess I'm a little confused because I thought the proportions were supposed to add to be 1

Comment: @barnsm2 You're right, using `xtabs` might be better here, see updated answer. Note that using `hospdead` just gives 1:0, so I used the more interesting `death` variable.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways to do this but the simplest is probably via the `aggregate` function.

```
> aggregate( hospdead ~ (dnrday<=3) , SB_xlsx1 , mean)

  dnrday <= 3  hospdead
1       FALSE 0.1428571
2        TRUE 0.0000000
```